# Multiple time-series symbolic regression

Tags: r, regression, time-series, multiple-regression, python

I have few columns of technical data as a time-series, let's say column a, column b and column c. I want to find out the impact of both a and b on c.

If I search for these keywords I find

- [pandas corr function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) that computes (several) correlation coefficients on (only) two columns.
- models like ARMA or ARIMA where the first "A" means autoregressive that's a regression of the same but time-lagged column.

So, what I am looking for is a kind of symbolic regression (or similar) that can compute correlations of **several** columns of time series on another.

Comment: This can be modeled by VAR models - this link holds nice explanations and examples - https://econometricswithr.wordpress.com/time-series/an-introduction-to-vector-autoregression-var/

Comment: @DaFanat, I think you are incorrect. A VAR model takes several dependent variables and they are endogeneous. In this case we have one dependent variable and the other two are presumably exogenous. Thus there are two reasons for why a VAR model is not appropriate here.

Comment: tardis, how is your situation different from the standard multiple regression setup? What prevents you from running a regression of c on a and b? Or perhaps of c on lags of a and b, if you suspect some lag?

Comment: @RichardHardy you make a good point about the not stated model assumptions. If indeed a,b are considered independent, then VAR models are not the right tool. tardis, do you have any reason to believe a affects b or vice versa?

Comment: @DaFanat, regardless of whether a affects b, b affects a, both or none a VAR model is not well suited because of the two reasons I listed above.

Comment: Tardis, could you answer my question in a previous comment? Are you sure you cannot just run a regression $c=\beta_0+\beta_1a+\beta_2b+\varepsilon$? Wouldn't that answer your question?

Comment: Use a multi-channel LSTM or RNN.